# Validation error 422 on the login page in fastapi login page

Tags: python, fastapi

I am working on this code. I am getting validation error 422 on this code and am not able to figure it out the issue

**main.py**

```py
@app.post("/loginsuccess/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_success(request: Request, username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    p = await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(await User.get(username=username, password=password))
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(p)
    if json_compatible_item_data is not None:
        logger.info("Logged in Successfully")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("homepage.html", {"request": request, "username":username})
    else:
        status_code:int
        status_code = 500
        logger.error("Invalid Credentials")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request, "status_code":status_code})
```

The error i have given the screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHH1.png)

Comment: You should only tag the framework you use, and not every framework you ever heard of.

Comment: I am not getting any response if i tag only fastapi

Comment: Please include the _actual_ error message in the question itself. Do not include it as an image, as they're hard to search for and have bad accessibility. The screenshot only includes the definition of the 422 error, not the actual error you're getting. Tagging other frameworks will NOT get you an answer from people who know FastAPI. Please do not do that.

Comment: You need to put the *actual* error response you get when calling the API. A 422 error response usually has some details on where the validation fails, something like telling you which field is invalid. If you are making the request with something like Postman or `curl`, please [edit] to post the response that you get. The Swagger/OpenAPI doc of the 422 Example Value is not useful.

Comment: I have no clue about FastAPI. I came here because you tagged the question with Flask. You wasted my time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the form values directly from the request

```py
async def login_success(request: Request):
    form = await self.request.form()
    username = form.get('username', '').lower().strip()
    password = form.get('password', '').strip()
```

This should help you find where your error is. If username and password are empty, then you'll want to double check your HTML form